# Get Unique data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table with some data , which is shown as below.

[image]

I want to get unique data from the table and i have tried below code

```
SELECT
    sa.EMPID,
    sa.EMPNAME,
    sa.DEPTID
FROM dbo.Sample AS sa
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Sample AS se ON sa.EMPID = se.EMPID
```

but not able to get the result.

I want the query to get below data

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this query..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT EMPNAME,
       DEPTID,
       MIN(EMPID) AS EMPID
       FROM  dbo.Sample
 GROUP BY EMPNAME, DEPTID
```

Comment: Easiest solution ever. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME, DEPTID
FROM (
    SELECT
        EMPID,
        EMPNAME,
        DEPTID,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPNAME, DEPTID ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM dbo.[Sample]
) t
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `group by` `empname` and `deptid`, and select the minimal `empid`:

```
SELECT     MIN(sa.EMPID), sa.EMPNAME, sa.DEPTID
FROM       dbo.Sample AS sa LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.Sample AS se ON sa.EMPID = se.EMPID
GROUP BY   sa.EMPNAME, sa.DEPTID
```

Comment: This a clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
With tmp AS
FROM (SELECT S.EMPID,S.EMPNAME,S.DEPTID,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.EMPNAME, S.DEPTID ORDER BY S.EMPID)
    FROM dbo.[Sample] S LEFT JOIN dbo.[Sample] T ON T.EMPID = S.EMPID)     
SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPTID FROM tmp WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this what you want :

```
SELECT Min(EMPID) AS EMPID,
EMPNAME,
DEPTID
FROM dbo.Sample
Group By EMPNAME, DEPTID
```